# MS Access query is there any Simpler Method to get the MAX value from multiple columns with multiple LEFT JOIN

Tags: ms-access

MS Access Query any simple method to get the MAX value from multiple columns with multiple LEFT JOIN

```
myQry = "SELECT A.id,
MAX(B.time) AS Sub1_MaxTime, 
MAX(C.time) AS Sub2_MaxTime, 
MAX(D.time) AS Sub3_MaxTime,
IIF(IIF(Sub1_MaxTime > Sub2_MaxTime, Sub1_MaxTime, Sub2_MaxTime) > Sub3_MaxTime, IIF(Sub1_MaxTime > Sub2_MaxTime, Sub1_MaxTime, Sub2_MaxTime),Sub3_MaxTime) AS MaxCombinedTime
FROM((MainTable AS A 
LEFT JOIN SubTable_1 AS B ON B..mainid = A.id) 
LEFT JOIN SubTable_2 AS C ON C..mainid = A.id)
LEFT JOIN SubTable_3 AS D ON D.mainid = A.id 
GROUP by A.id ";
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you have 3 tables with same kind of data? Can UNION the 3 tables and then use that query as source for an aggregate query. Otherwise, use VBA.

Comment: hi, ya three tables for three diffrent services. And i did it it through Union querry and group. But its taking little more time than LEFT Join. Because lot of data in the three tables. And I am trying diff methods.

Comment: SELECT A.MaxSubTime FROM MainTable 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT mainid, Max(time) AS MaxSubTime 
FROM
(SELECT mainid, time FROM SubTable_1
UNION
SELECT mainid, time FROM SubTable_2
UNION
SELECT  mainid, time FROM SubTable_3) 
GROUP BY mainid) AS A ON A.mainid = MainTable.id   Is this is right method? or any  anybody can optimise it?

Comment: Do those 3 table have very different fields? If not, should be one table with another field for service type.

Comment: Hi, ya the three sub tables have few other fields with different colum fields. Only the "time" field  and  "mainid " field are similar in those three tables.

Comment: But ya, you gave me good suggestion, I am thinking to merge these three in to one.